# Bootstrap 3: Two forms on the same line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have made two forms for registering. When i add the code below to the page the second field automatically drops down below the first one. I would like it to go besides it.

```
<h1>Register</h1>


<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Forename" autofocus style="width:150px">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Surname" autofocus style="width:150px">
```

here is an example of what it looks like in normal html ([currently](http://jsfiddle.net/wemTM/)) and that is what i want it to look like. But in bootstrap it keeps taking  new line

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reference the [inline form styling](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline) on Bootstrap's site.

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Enter email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword2">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
</form>
```

Alternatively, you can also [use columns](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-sizes) to put form elements next to one another:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=".col-lg-2">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=".col-lg-3">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=".col-lg-4">
  </div>
</div>
```